# AWS Lightsail Cloud9 Install Fails

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

When I am trying to load the Cloud9 IDE for my AWS Lightsail instance it gives me this error:

```
Installation Started

Package Cloud9 IDE 1
--------------------
Python version 2.7 is required to install pty.js. Please install Python 2.7 and try again. You can find more information on how to install Python in the docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/cloud9/python-ssh
exiting with 1

Failed Bash. Exit code 1
```

My Lightsail instance does have python 2.7.15 installed (when I do python --version).  Does anyone know a solution to this issue?

Comment: I found an answer, just in case anyone else finds this and has a problem the answer is to run this to ensure C9 is looking in the right spot:

`curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/c9/install/master/install.sh | bash`

This resolved my issue.

Comment: for the sake of the next person could you put your resolution as an answer and mark it answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### Here's the walkthrough on connecting your AWS cloud9 IDE to your AWS Lightsail instance (Wordpress, Node, Python etc).

Go to https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/webapp/home/instances

Create an instance using UNIX/Linux/Wordpress or Node or whatever floats your boat. ->

click create instance

Go to networking and Create a static IP for the instance

Go to manage instance and connect using the web based SSH shell

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y python-minimal

sudo apt-get update

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash

. ~/.bashrc

nvm install node

which node (should print sonething like => /home/bitnami/.nvm/versions/node/v11.13.0/bin/node)

curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/c9/install/master/install.sh | bash

wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/c9/install/master/install.sh | bash

go to https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/home

create a new environment using SSH

enter the username bitnami and the static IP of the instance from lightsail

Environment Path =>   /home/bitnami

Node Path -> enter the value of 'which node' command from lightsail =>
(e.g. /home/bitnami/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/bin/node)

At the bottom of the new cloud9 configuration, there's an SSH key, highlight and copy that.

Go back to the cloud terminal in lightsail =>
  run   vi ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Add the Cloud9 ssh key 2 lines after the default key

Go back to your cloud9 environment and click 'create Environment' once the SSH key has been added and saved

You should now be connected to your lightsail instance through AWS cloud9